# Javascript / Jquery search behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to figure out the proper syntax to access a variable in a loop

To start with an object/array is populated with this

```
var curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']");
```

I get a list populated fine with the inputs that I'm looking for.
When I enter this code to reference a specific index I type

```
console.log(curInputs[0]);
```

and I get this, which is expected

```
<input type="text" class="myclass" id="myID">
```

Where I am stuck is what if I want to go further and do something like this?

```
console.log(curInputs[0].attr('class'));
```

It tells me curInputs[0].attr is not a function. Im expecting to see "myClass". How can I do the equivalent thing correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
console.log(curInputs.attr('class'));
```

The `[0]` returns the JavaScript object, while you want the jQuery element.

If you want to iterate over the search results elements, use `each()`, eg.

```
curInputs.each( function( index, element ){
    console.log( $( this ).attr(“class”));
});
```

Comment: You are right with that!  I figured it out right before I got this answer.  That always happens after hours of searching beforehand. For me what solved it was wrapping in jquery like $(curInputs[0]).attr('class') which is what I needed to do in the jquery loop.  Thanks!

Comment: There's also `curInputs.eq(0)`